# I want to print index of all elements without using forEach or filter or map

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

Here is my code it is giving me the same index number of the element.

I want it like this `0,1,2,3,4,5,6`

```
let as=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5,5]

for(let i=0;i<as.length;i++){
  console.log(as[i], as.indexOf(as[i]))
}
```

Here is my output **:**

```
1 0
2 1
3 2
4 3
5 4
5 4
5 4
```

Comment: just use i? console.log(as[i], i)  am i misunderstanding what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to fetch the index of the elements available in an array. If Yes, Then you can do like this **:**

```js
let as = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5,5];

const indexArray = as.map((item, index) => index);

console.log(indexArray.join(','));
```

Answer (score -1):

Create an array you can push the indexes into, and then create a string with [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

```js
const as = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5];
let out = [];

for (let i = 0; i < as.length; i++) {
  out.push(i);
}

console.log(out.join(','));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
let as=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5,5]

for(let i=0;i<as.length;i++){
  console.log(as[i], as.indexOf(as[i],i))
}
```

Explaination: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf